# Plot timeseries of volume on the y-axis and year + week number on the x-axis with type determined by hue

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

## import libraries

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib as mpl
import seaborn as sns
from datetime import datetime
%matplotlib inline
import warnings; warnings.filterwarnings(action='once')
```

## import data

```
df = pd.read_excel("CDS Detail - 2019 05 22 - sample.xlsx")
```

## check data format

```
df.head()
Date                Status  Method  Volume
2018-05-10 20:45:28 F   Discretionary   1
2018-05-03 21:09:10 F   Discretionary   1
2018-05-17 14:19:47 F   Discretionary   1
2018-05-17 14:21:17 F   Discretionary   1
2018-05-17 14:19:47 F   Discretionary   1
```

## remove null values

```
df = df[df['Date'].notnull()]
```

## check types

```
df.columns
Index(['Status', 'Method', 'Volume', 'Date'], dtype='object')
df.dtypes
Status            object
Method            object
Volume             int64
Date      datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

## review data header

```
df.head()
Status  Method  Volume  Date
0   F   Discretionary   1   2018-05-10 20:45:28
1   F   Discretionary   1   2018-05-03 21:09:10
2   F   Discretionary   1   2018-05-17 14:19:47
3   F   Discretionary   1   2018-05-17 14:21:17
4   F   Discretionary   1   2018-05-17 14:19:47
```

## reset axis using datetime64 as index

```
df = df.set_index('Date')

df.head()
Status  Method  Volume
Date            
2018-05-10 20:45:28 F   Discretionary   1
2018-05-03 21:09:10 F   Discretionary   1
2018-05-17 14:19:47 F   Discretionary   1
2018-05-17 14:21:17 F   Discretionary   1
2018-05-17 14:19:47 F   Discretionary   1

weekly = df.resample(rule='W').sum()
```

## confirm data has been resampled by week. Note the missing 'Method' feature

```
weekly
Date        Volume
2018-04-08  7
2018-04-15  10
2018-04-22  40
2018-04-29  69
2018-05-06  128
2018-05-13  380
2018-05-20  464
2018-05-27  6052
2018-06-03  6095
2018-06-10  6224
2018-06-17  3084
2018-06-24  5
```

## basic matplotlib chart to check data will chart as weekly volume   `weekly.plot()`

## now how do we add 'Method' as the legend to create a lineplot with lines for each method class?

## this is where I am getting stuck. How do I use this style plot x-axis as date and y-axis as volume with multiple lines for each 'Method?

```
sns.lineplot(data = weekly, hue = 'Method')
```

Comment: please add a sample dataset and what you tried until now

Comment: @Gio updated the post based on your comments. Appreciate the help as I am new to Stackoverflow. Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you may be missing `x` and `y` in the `lineplot` call. Try this without resetting index.

```
sns.lineplot(data = weekly,  x='Date', y='Volume', hue = 'Method')
```

see example here: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html